# How to show percentages on the pie chart in Tableau, as opposed to off of it?

Tags: tableau-api

In Tableau Public 10.4, I am trying to find the setting that allows me to move the percentages of the following pie chart on to the slices, versus off of them (as they currently are). Is there a way to do this?

Thanks!

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You could do it manually:
http://onlinehelp.tableau.com/current/pro/desktop/en-us/annotations_marklabels_move.html

Or do it a hacky way if you want it 'automatically:
https://community.tableau.com/thread/123584